# Inject ViewModel with Dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, dagger

I am building an Android application with Dagger2 and the new Architecture Components. I have tried to make ViewModels injectable following this tutorial: https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/understanding-dagger-2-multibindings-viewmodel-8418eb372848

When I run my code, I get the following error:

```
[AndroidInjector.inject(T) Map<Class<? extends ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

My code looks like this:

```
@Singleton
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
        private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass]
                ?: creators.asIterable().firstOrNull { modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key) }?.value
                ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class $modelClass")

        return creator.get() as T
    }
}

@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}

@MapKey
@Target(FUNCTION, PROPERTY_GETTER, PROPERTY_SETTER)
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

I the module is also included in the AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    ViewModelFactoryModule::class // ...
])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<BaseApplication>

class BaseApplication : DaggerApplication(), HasActivityInjector {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(AppModule(this)).build()
    }
```

The ViewModel I try to inject is declared in a Module like this:

```
@Module
abstract class SettingsModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SettingsViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindSettingsViewModel(model: SettingsViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

Does anybody have an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Please see [here] for general information and provide the relevant parts including the **full error message** _in your question_. We can't help you if we have to guess what parts of your code are used where and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to point exact issue with Dagger. Try moving the

```
@Binds
@IntoMap
@ViewModelKey(SettingsViewModel::class)
abstract fun bindSettingsViewModel(model: SettingsViewModel): ViewModel
```

from `SettingsModule` to `ViewModelFactoryModule` as that's what I am doing in my code-base and it's working.

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): 
                                      ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

OR

Try changing your `ViewModelKey` to this:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

Comment: Moving this ViewModel bindings to the ViewModelFactoryModule worked, thank you very much!

Comment: @SimonSchiller I'm glad Simon